# Django Admin: IntegrityError When Adding New or Modifying Existing Models From Django Admin Panel in Browser

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-models, django-admin

I'm encountering a peculiar issue when attempting to add or update existing models through the Django Admin panel. It results in the following error:

`IntegrityError at /admin/main/user/2/change/` 
`FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`

Here are the details:

- `Django Version: 4.2.4`
- `Exception Type: IntegrityError`
- `Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`
- `Exception Location: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oracle\Site #041\site\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py, line 313, in _commit`
- `Occurred during: django.contrib.admin.options.change_view`
- `Python Version: 3.12.0`
- `Python Executable: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oracle\Site #041\site\env\Scripts\python.exe`

This error happens when I try to update or add data to an existing model. However, it's worth noting that when I update or add new data using my custom admin interface, everything works as expected.

I'm seeking assistance in understanding the root cause of this issue and how to resolve it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What do your models look like? Did you define your custom "Forms" or are you using the built-in ones?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @TymoteuszLao. I have figured it out myself. It turns out that I had deleted my own account from the Django admin, which was causing this error. I have provided the link below to help anyone who is experiencing the same issue.

https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/in4dp3/foreign_key_constraint_failed_when_user_deletes/